# Format date in AWS's style

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, time, date-formatting

I'm looking to compare the dates of some AWS resources in an external script so I need to match AWS's date/time format.

[AWS' own documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutTimestamp.html) states that the date must be **the complete date plus hours, minutes, and seconds**, however date formats end up looking like `2017-07-27T15:47:59.373Z`, where my hardcoding of `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%SZ` gets me only `2017-07-15T11:39.29Z`.

Side by side, that's:

```
AWS: ???                - 2017-07-27T15:47:59.373Z
Me:  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%SZ - 2017-07-15T11:39.29Z
```

There's something on the end that's adding a few extra digits. What am I missing to get the formatting identical?

Comment: The "extra digits" is the milliseconds. Are you using bash's `date` command? If that's the case, try with `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ`

Comment: @Hugo So it is! Feel free to make it an answer so I can upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "extra digits" is the milliseconds.

I'm assuming you're using bash's `date` command. If that's the case, try with:

```
date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ"
```

The `-u` option gets the date in UTC (so it's compliant with the `Z`, which is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)).

If you don't use `-u`, it'll print the date and time in the system's timezone (which can't necessarily be UTC).